# How to send multiple data strings back to MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to send multiple input fields from one activity to main activity using intents. But my app is not running after that point.

My code of taking input is:-

Code in child activity to send data

```
ivHappy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("name",etName.getText());
            intent.putExtra("number",etNumber.getText());
            intent.putExtra("website",etWebsite.getText());
            intent.putExtra("loc",etLocation.getText());
            intent.putExtra("smileyCode",1);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            Activity2.this.finish();
        }
    });
```

Code to receive data

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==ACTIVITY2){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            int x = Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra("smileyCode"));
            if(x==1){
                ivPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.happy);
            }
            if(x==2){
                ivPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.neutral);
            }
            if(x==3){
                ivPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad);
            }
            number = data.getStringExtra("number");
            name = data.getStringExtra("name");
            website = data.getStringExtra("website");
            location = data.getStringExtra("loc");

            ivPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ivDial.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ivWeb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ivLoc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

But this is not working. So how should I send multiple input back to mainActivity?

Comment: The `smileyCode` was "put" as an integer and you are trying to receive/parse as a string - given code just use `getIntExtra` - or put it as a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me. In addition to this i added toString() method after every getText() method. After that it is working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your child activity while you are getting texts, you should convert them to string. Like this theName.getText().toString()

Answer (score 0):

Try below as it's always better to send and receive data in String so conversion error occur's but in this way you have to make your `onActivityResult` method intelligent enough to know if this extra is String or Int or Float etc.Currently there is no way around it but i think soon [SafeArgs](https://medium.com/@vepetruskova/using-safe-args-plugin-current-state-of-affairs-41b1f01e7de8) will solve this problem *(i wish)*

while setting Extra keep everything in Int.

```
        intent.putExtra("name",etName.getText());
        intent.putExtra("number",etNumber.getText());
        intent.putExtra("website",etWebsite.getText());
        intent.putExtra("loc",etLocation.getText());
        intent.putExtra("smileyCode",Integer.toString(1));
```

while extracting Extra convert string to given required type.

```
        intent.getExtra("name");
        intent.getExtra("number");
        intent.getExtra("website");
        intent.getExtra("loc");
        Integer.valueOf(intent.getExtra("smileyCode"));
```